# rsync daemon permission denied problem under docker

Tags: permissions, rsync, users, docker

I'm trying to follow [this article](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2019/05/incremental-docker-builds-using-ccache.html) and am having trouble running a very straightforward rsync daemon docker container. it is not able to receive files, and gives the error 13 permission denied even though everything should be running as root including the rsync daemon process. Here I have prepared a simple example to easily reproduce the issue and it is reproducible without even doing any networking at all.

```bash
❯ cat rsync_daemon.Dockerfile      
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache rsync \
    && mkdir -p /opt/share \
    && echo "testcontent" > /opt/share/testfile \
    && echo "[share]" > /etc/rsyncd.conf \
    && echo "path = /opt/share" >> /etc/rsyncd.conf  \
    && echo "hosts allow = *" >> /etc/rsyncd.conf \
    && echo "read only = false" >> /etc/rsyncd.conf

CMD rsync --daemon --port 9999 && while sleep 1; do /bin/true; done
```

```bash
❯ mkdir context # create empty dir to use as docker context
❯ docker build -t rsync_manual -f rsync_daemon.Dockerfile context
```

Builds without incident and you can confirm if you follow along.

```bash
docker run -d --rm --name rsyncd_manual rsync_manual
```

Detached container run initiates fine.

```bash
docker exec -it rsyncd_manual sh
```

That injects an interactive shell into the container and then I test. It can copy from the daemon fine but daemon cannot receive files:

```
/ # ls -la /opt/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:21 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:21 share
/ # ls -la /opt/share/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:21 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:21 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            12 Sep 30 02:21 testfile
/ # ls
bin    dev    etc    home   lib    media  mnt    opt    proc   root   run    sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
/ # rsync -r rsync://localhost:9999/share dest
/ # ls -la dest
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:23 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep 30 02:23 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            12 Sep 30 02:23 testfile
/ # cat dest/testfile
testcontent
/ # mkdir src
/ # echo 'testdata' > src/testdata
/ # rsync -r src rsync://localhost:9999/share
rsync: [generator] recv_generator: mkdir "/src" (in share) failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1327) [sender=3.2.5]
/ # ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh -c rsync --daemon --port 9999 && while sleep 1; do /bin/true; done
    8 root      0:00 rsync --daemon --port 9999
   79 root      0:00 sh
 1382 root      0:00 sleep 1
 1383 root      0:00 ps aux
```

Anyone know what the hell's going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK this is weird...

`chmod g+w /opt/share/` allows it to work. But in my other test (which is only slightly less simplified compared to the above, it bindmounts a dir on the host into the rsync daemon share), I had to `chmod o+w`!!

What I want to know is why when `/opt/share/` had `drwxr-xr-x` perms rsync cannot write to it. Rsync is running as root, not as `rsync` as far as I can tell. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: At the end of the day I'm going to `chmod go+w` and get on with my life but I really really want to know what part of basic linux that I've failed to account for here because it must be something really simple.

Comment: Something I can report is once i got this working with `chmod go+w` the new dirs that are successfully being created are owned by `nobody nogroup` which is hinting that it's probably something docker and user related that I'm not accounting for here.

Comment: `rsyncd.conf` has a `uid` and `gid` parameter that defines which user account does the actual file transfer even when the daemon is running as root. `nobody` is the default value for both, which seems to account for your observations.